# Zebra Label zpl not showing completely in physical but yes virtual print

Tags: printing, label, zpl

Hello I am trying to print a zpl label, it works virtually fine for me but they have sent me physical tests of the label from the printer and it does not print 3 letters that are to the right. Attached image.

any suggestions?

Code Label ZPL:

```
"^XA^DFR:FOR_ALV.ZPL^FS
^PRC
^LH0,0^FS
^LL504
^MD8
^MMT
^MNY
^LH0,0^FS
^FO48,8^A0N,56,49^CI13^FR^FN17^FS
^FO160,8^A0N,56,49^CI13^FR^FN1^FS
^FO480,8^A0N,75,49^CI13^FR^FN16^FS
^FO48,63^A0N,56,49^CI13^FR^FN10^FS
^FO350,63^A0N,56,49^CI13^FR^FN15^FS
^FO550,83^A0N,32,41^CI13^FR^FN8^FS
^FO48,130^A0N,24,36^CI13^FR^FN2^FS
^FO48,155^A0N,24,36^CI13^FR^FN3^FS
^FO48,180^A0N,24,36^CI13^FR^FN4^FS
^FO48,205^A0N,24,36^CI13^FR^FN5^FS
^FO48,230^A0N,32,36^CI13^FR^FN6^FS
^FO48,260^A0N,32,25^CI13^FR^FN9^FS
^FO178,260^A0N,32,25^CI13^FR^FN7^FS
^FO290,260^A0N,24,36^CI13^FR^FN12^FS
^FO400,260^A0N,32,41^CI13^FR^FN14^FS
^FO500,260^A0N,32,41^CI13^FR^FN13^FS
^FO030,305^A0N,29,36^CI13^FR^FDBUSINESSS.A. C.V.^FS
^FO030,335^A0N,29,36^CI13^FR^FDNAME OTHER^FS
^FO030,360^A0N,33,36^CI13^FR^FDwww.webpage.com.^FS
^FO030,390^A0N,33,36^CI13^FR^FN18^FS
^FO585,205^A0N,70,130^CI13^FR^FN19^FS
^FO595,305^A0N,70,130^CI13^FR^FN20^FS
^FO585,405^A0N,70,130^CI13^FR^FN21^FS
^BY5,3.0^FO030,424^BCN,72,N,Y,N^FR^FN11^FS
^XZ
^XA^XFR:FOR_ALV.ZPL^FS
^FN1^FDCOUNTRY^FS
^FN2^FDDESTINYL^FS
^FN3^FDSTREETII   #Ext 17804^FS
^FN4^FDVISTAS DEL MAR ^FS
^FN5^FDSTATE, COUNTRY^FS
^FN6^FD1 CARRO 2^FS
^FN7^FD09:59^FS
^FN8^FD^FS
^FN9^FD04/01/21^FS
^FN10^FDY19561^FS
^FN11^FD>:Y19561^FS
^FN12^FD108.3^FS
^FN13^FDDE 1^FS
^FN14^SN001,1,N^FS
^FN15^FD0^FS
0^FS
^FN17^FDCON^FS
^FN18^FDTEL ^FS
^FN19^FDC^FS
^FN20^FDO^FS
^FN21^FDN^FS
^PQ1,0,0,N
^XZ
"
```

attached image of the label virtula, the size is 4 x 2 .6:

[image]

attached image of the label physical the size is 4x2.6: Label not show "C O N"
[image]

Comment: My guess its printing off the label. Fiddle with it until it works

Comment: I moved the letters to the left margin, I can't do them physically, they only send me if it worked or not. I am on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually occurs when the print width is configured to be less than the physical label width.  Use the `^PW` command to set the width.  For a 4" label at 203dpi, for example, add `^PW812` to the top of your label format, right after the `^PRC`.

NOTE: If you are using the full with of the label and you don't know the physical size of the label or the printer dpi, you could set the `PRINT WITH` to something insanely large, it will automatically be truncated to the correct value. From the [docs](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/PW_Command.pdf):

> If the value exceeds the width of the label, the width is set to the
> label’s maximum size

Comment: i will try this.

Comment: NOTE1: Take extra note of the dpi of the printer. I was used to 203dpi printer and moved to a 300dpi printer. I did check the `PRINT WIDTH` setting and it was the same at both printers. In retrospect it is obvious this was wrong, but it took me a while to figure it out.